# Nodejs Express API Error 400 on POST request

Tags: node.js, api, express, post

everything I try it just doesn't work. Im trying to make a post requiest on api to register an account, and every time I get the 400 error code.

here is my authRoutes:

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const User = require('../models/userModel');

router.get('/signup', (req, res, next) => {
    res.status('200').render('register')
});

router.post('/signup', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const user = new User(req.body.name, req.body.email, req.body.password)
        user.secretKey = process.env.SECRET_KEY
        const response = await fetch(`${process.env.API_URL}/auth/signup`, {
            method: 'post',
            body: JSON.stringify(user),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        })
        const userCreated = await response.json()
        res.cookie('token', userCreated.token)
        if (userCreated.error) {
            res.status('400').send('registerError', {
                userCreated
             })
        } else {
            res.status('200').redirect('/')
        }
    } catch (err) {
        res.status('400').send('400')
    }
})


module.exports = router;
```

and here i have my register.ejs

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/signuptest.css">
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/signup" method="POST">
        <div class="container">
          <h1>Register</h1>
          <p>Please fill in this form to create an account.</p>
          <hr>
      
          <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" id="email" required>
      
          <label for="psw"><b>Name</b></label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" name="name" id="name" required>
      
          <label for="psw-repeat"><b>Repeat Password</b></label>
          <input type="password" placeholder=" Password" name="password" id="password" required>
          <hr>
      
          <p>By creating an account you agree to our <a href="#">Terms & Privacy</a>.</p>
          <button type="submit" class="registerbtn">Register</button>
        </div>
      
        <div class="container signin">
          <p>Already have an account? <a href="#">Sign in</a>.</p>
        </div>
      </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my userModel.js:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema( {
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    email: {type: String,  required: true},
    password: {type: String, required: true}

});


module.exports = User = mongoose.model('UserSchema', UserSchema);
```

Please tell me what am I doing wrong because I don't know where to look, i tried testing all with console.log but it didn't show anything.
I tested the req.body and I get the email, name, password...

Comment: try logging error in catch block

Comment: i get this in console.log "ObjectParameterError: Parameter "obj" to Document() must be an object, got carmina@gmail.com"

Comment: Oh, got it, You have wrote 
` const user = new User(req.body.name, req.body.email, req.body.password) ` 
It should be 
` const user = new User({ name: req.body.name, email: req.body.email, password: req.body.password})`